# Unable to combine line and two scatter plots in xlsxwriter. Also having problems coloring plot symbols

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a spreadsheet plot with a line and two scatter charts.  I am trying to have different symbols for each scatter chart:

```
# create the chart and add it to the workbook:
value_line_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
value_line_chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Values'})
value_line_chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Time'})
value_line_chart.set_title({'name': 'Chart of {}'.format(historical_data.symbol)})
value_line_chart.add_series({
    'line': {
        'color': 'cyan',
        'width': .5
    },
    'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, value_col, last_col, value_col],
    'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_col, date_col],
    'name': "data",
})
scatter_buy_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
scatter_buy_chart.add_series({
    'marker': {
        'type': 'long_dash',
        'size': 5,
        'border': {'color': 'red'},
        'fill': {'color': 'red'},
    },
    'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, buy_action_col, last_col, buy_action_col],
    'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_col, date_col],
    'name': "buy",
})
value_line_chart.combine(scatter_buy_chart)
scatter_sell_chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
scatter_sell_chart.add_series({
    'marker': {
        'type': 'plus',
        'size': 5,
        'border': {'color': 'green'},
        'fill': {'color': 'green'},
    },
    'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, sell_action_col, last_col, sell_action_col],
    'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_col, date_col],
    'name': "buy",
})
value_line_chart.combine(scatter_sell_chart)
value_line_chart.set_size({'width': 720, 'height': 576})
value_line_chart.set_x_axis({
    'date_axis': True,
    'min': date_data[0],
    'max': date_data[len(date_data)-1]
})
value_line_chart.set_legend({'none': True})
worksheet.insert_chart('B1', value_line_chart)
workbook.close()
```

The problems that I am having are:

1. I am unable to get the second scatter chart to show up
2. I am unable to get the colors of the symbols to change

I have tried rendering the line and scatter charts individually and the the data and symbol ***shapes*** show up correctly.

1. I am able to change the color of the line chart.
2. I am able to change the shape of the symbols.
3. I am able to render the line chart and only one of the two scatter charts.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get the results I was looking for by adding all of the series into the single chart:
[image]

```
# create the chart and add it to the workbook:
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Values'})
chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Time'})
chart.set_title({'name': 'Chart of {}'.format(historical_data.symbol)})
chart.add_series({
    'line': {
        'color': 'cyan',
        'width': .5
    },
    'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, value_col, last_col, value_col],
    'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_col, date_col],
    'name': "data",
})
chart.add_series({
    'marker': {
        'type': 'long_dash',
        'size': 8,
        'border': {'color': 'red'},
        'fill': {'color': 'red'},
    },
    'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, buy_action_col, last_col, buy_action_col],
    'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_col, date_col],
    'name': "buy",
})
chart.add_series({
    'marker': {
        'type': 'plus',
        'size': 8,
        'border': {'color': 'green'},
        'fill': {'color': 'green'},
    },
    'values': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, sell_action_col, last_col, sell_action_col],
    'categories': [worksheet.name, data_start_row, date_col, last_col, date_col],
    'name': "buy",
})
chart.set_size({'width': 720, 'height': 576})
chart.set_x_axis({
    'date_axis': True,
    'min': date_data[0],
    'max': date_data[len(date_data)-1]
})
chart.set_legend({'none': True})
worksheet.insert_chart('B1', chart)
workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn’t possible to combine more than 2 charts with XlsxWriter. That is a limitation of the library.